# Powerpoint vba opening excel and paste text and delimit by "|"

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint, csv

I want a powerpoint vba code which

1st: open new excel.
2nd: paste text from powerpoint slides into cell "A1".
3rd: In excel delimit cell "A1" by "|"

but codes upto 2nd step runs well but 3rd codes does not run.

When I have same codes in excel vba runned, it succeeded, but
In powerpoint vba it didn't.

what's the problem at my code below?

Public Sub LoadToExcel()

```
Dim xlApp As Object
Dim xlWorkBook As Object
Dim xlSheet As Object

Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xlApp.Visible = True
Set xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add
Set xlSheet = xlWorkBook.Sheets(1)

With xlSheet

   .Range("A1").Select
   .Paste

   .Columns("A:A").TextToColumns _
    Destination:=.Range("A1"), _
    DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
    ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, _
    Tab:=False, _
    Semicolon:=False, _
    Comma:=False, _
    Space:=False, _
    Other:=True, _
    OtherChar:="|", _
    FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1)), _
    TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

End With

Set xlApp = Nothing
Set xlWorkBook = Nothing
```

End Sub

Comment: You don't say exactly what the problem is. "Didn't succeed" isn't enough. But if you're trying to run this code in PPT, it won't even compile. You're using Excel constants in PPT:  xlDelimited, xlDoubleQuote, etc. You'll need to find their values and define them as Constants in your own code so PPT knows what they are.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. If you don't mind, could you recommend a good site to find the appropriate constants for ppt?

Comment: No site needed.  Simply go into the VBA IDE in any of the apps, open the Immediate window (press Ctrl+G) and type a question mark followed by the name of the constant you want to look up, then Enter:  ? xlDelimited for example.. The value of the constant will appear beneath.

Comment: As you pointed out I looked up the corresponding value for the constants. And I found out that both of them were 1. So in the source I added declaration code like this. Const xlDelimited As Variant = 1 (same as xlDoubleQuoure) But the result was the same. I mean that codes from the beginning to .Paste executed well as I intended but codes after .Paste I mean from .Columns("A:A").TextToColums to TrailingMinusNumbers:True didn't still executed. Is there another problem in my codes?

Comment: I tried this here; after changing both the XL constants in your code to literal 1s, I added a line of text in PPT with pipe symbols between words, selected the text, copied it then ran your code.  It worked.  Are you sure there's something appropriate on the clipboard when you run the code?

Comment: As you said finally I found that it was the problem about XL constants. I'm so excited that  after fixing the codes as you said, the entire codes worked as intended for the first time. Thank you for sparing time for me about this so far.